# Using Rate Limiting doesn't add Header to response and gets CORS error in client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bucket4j

I'm trying to adapt this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bucket4j#boot-starter) to my server using the Bucket4j Spring Boot Starter.
I'm using an application.properties file.
I can limit the api queries with no problem, but the client doesn't get a 429 error, on the client I get a CORS error.
I figure this is because I'm not adding a header to my server response when I'm limiting the api queries, but is there any way to add this throught the application.properties template?

On the [official documentation](https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter) there is a value called "bucket4j.filters[0].http-response-headers.<MY_CUSTOM_HEADER>=MY_CUSTOM_HEADER_VALUE" but I can't figure how to use it, did anybody use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid CORS errors by adding the proper header:

```
bucket4j.filters[0].http-response-headers.Access-Control-Allow-Origin="https://<clientUri>:<clientPort>"
```

and if you are using some form of authentication you may want to also add this:

```
bucket4j.filters[0].http-response-headers.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true
```

Comment: I tried your answer but still get an error.
My console says:
"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: i just realized i swapped the properties and corrected the answer accordingly, btw your error states that you indeed need to set the one containing Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Also make sure to be using the latest version of bucket4j, or these options probably won't work.

Comment: Sorry, i'm on the junior side of development, what are <clientUri> and <clientPort> params? I'm looking at them at my spring server and don't find anything like that.